# Ways to do Oracle DB to Cassandra DB migration or Import without local files

Tags: database, oracle, import, cassandra, database-migration

I'm tying to figure out a way to do DB to DB migration without using local files(CSV). Is there any direct way to do SQL/Oracle DB to cassandra Db. Mostly I'm just going to import a table from oracle to cassandra. I have checked the methods I'm aware of and they are all using an temporary file to extract the data and then load it into cassandra.

Can someone suggest any other alternate methods that can be carried out possibly in Windows with a free ETL tool or any other suggestion on how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You used to be able to use [sqoop to import data](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/ana/importingSqlToCqlOrCfs.html) but this is deprecated now so depending what version of Cassandra you use you might be able to employ this.

I would recommend using the [Datastax bulk loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html) but you will have to export from oracle to json or csv first. You'd probably also have to do some transformation on your data anyway since its unlikely you'll have the same data model in Cassandra as you did with Oracle.